# Select Multiple options from dropdown list in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my project, i need to select multiple options from a drop down. My code looks something like this:

```
//Controller
$scope.data = [{id: 1, Country: Zambia},
              {id: 2, Country: United Kingdom}
              {id: 3, Country: USA}]

$scope.selectedCountry = [];


//view
   <select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model=" selectedCountry" multiple
      ng-options="country.country as country.country for country in data"></select>
<h4> {{selectedCountry}}</h4>
```

The context above works and i can select multiple options from the dropdown. This [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) helped me to achieve this.

The problem.
Now the problem i'm having is that when i select the options from the dropdown i need to be able to pass the id and country in the selectedCountry array and not just the country. so for instance in the above context when you select the first country , the information passed through  the to the selectedCountry Array will be something like this ["zambia"] but really what i'm looking for is something like this 
`[{id: 1, Country Zambia}].`

To solve this problem i attempted to do this in the view:

```
   <select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model=" selectedCountry" multiple
      ng-options="{Id: country.Id, Country: country.country } as country.country for country in data"></select>
<h4> {{selectedCountry}}</h4>
```

That worked well and the data passed to the selectedCountry array is an object like `{id: 1, Country: zambia}` but the issue is that i cannot select multiple options from the dropdown i can only select 1 option.
What am i doing wrong? and what is the best way to achieve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some mistakes in your code:

- Your JSON data is invalid. JSON string values must be in double
  quote, the same for keys `{"key":"value"}`. Every item in an array
  must be splitted by commas.
- The correct key for the country name is "Country".
- I'm using Angular 1.4.8.

You can use a shorter version of your code by using: `country.Country for country in data`

Something like this:

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  app.controller("controller", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.selectedCountry = [];
      $scope.data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "Country": "Zambia"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "Country": "United Kingdom"
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "Country": "USA"
      }];
    }
  ]);

})();
```

```css
div {
  margin: 2px;
}
.largeversion {
  border: solid 1px #FF0000;
}
.shortversion {
  border: solid 1px #005500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="controller">
    <div class="largeversion">
      <pre>ng-options="{Id: country.Id, Country: country.Country } as country.Country for country in data"</pre>
      <select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model=" selectedCountry" multiple ng-options="{Id: country.Id, Country: country.Country } as country.Country for country in data"></select>

    </div>
    <div class="shortversion">
      <pre>ng-options="country.Country for country in data"</pre>
      <select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model=" selectedCountry" multiple ng-options="country.Country for country in data"></select>

    </div>
    <h4> {{selectedCountry}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```